# Self-homeomorphisms of the Cantor set

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, reference-request, cantor-set

Let $C$ be the Cantor set. I was wondering about what we know about the topological group $Homeo(C)$ of self-homeomorphisms of $C$. I am looking for example for a classification of its elements (I have very little hope for that), or at least writing it as some limit of a family of well-known groups. Do we know its homology ? I have heard it is related to the Thompson and Higman-Thompson groups.

Do you know some reference that may give me some information about this group ?

Comment: I think Thompson's groups embed into the group of self-homeomorphisms of $C$.

Comment: Recall that the Cantor set can also be expressed as the infinite product $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. This representation makes it easier to produce explicit examples of self-homeomorphisms.

Comment: We know a lot about $G=\mathrm{Homeo}(C)$: it is a simple group, it has a comeager conjugacy class so in some sense almost all of its element look the same, there is a classification of the minimal homeorphisms of the Cantor space, the universal minimal flow of $G$ has an explicit description, $G$ is known to be acyclic etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. This article https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.00459 by Konstantin Andritsch computes the cohomology of G.